# I see some weid WordPress urls in my "Recent log messages", but i am using drupal

Tags: log-messages

Lately i am having an issue with Drupal, i don't know how to solve it, i get too many "page not found"  errors, but when i check the log, i found out that all of those URLs are Wordpress URLs, as you may see the in attached images.

What could be the issue?

[image: wordpress urls]

Comment: Those are probably from crawlers. You can validate this by examining the web server access log.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67812746/someone-made-some-wp-wlwmanifest-xml-http-requests-but-why

Answer (score 3):

It is just an external script that scans your site to find any security issue to attack it. It happened to my personal site too.
Those log entries are not caused by any issue on your site.

The only effect those attempts to access non-existent pages could have is that they could slow down your site, if they are repeated many times in few seconds.

Comment: I would fix the 404s with some catch alls or htaccess denial, then disable the database log module. That will lighten the constant read/writes to the database and ease the 404 requests to the server.